# How do I force Visual Studio 2017 to downgrade to a previous .NET Core version

Tags: azure, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

How do I downgrade the Microsoft.NETCore.App package in Visual Studio 2017?

The package manager shows it as 'Blocked by project'

[image: VS 2017 Package Manager]

I need to do this as Azure web apps do not yet have the 1.1.2 .NET Core runtime installed.

Answer (score 1):

A specific version of the package can be used by editing the csproj file and adding a package reference that specifies **Update** instead of **Include**

`<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />`