# Nuget Packages Conflict .net core

Tags: .net-core

I'm working on creating sample for clean architecture. When I had made core and infrastructure projects there were no problems. No I had add new API project and I got problem, picture bellow
[image]

I had tried to add project references in csproj but still have a problem, can anyone help me to fix this problem ?

Here is the link for project: https://github.com/danijel88/Clean-Architecture

Regards,
Danijel

Comment: Try to update your project to use net core 2.2. It seem you have installed the nuget packages for EF in a version upper than 2.1

Comment: Thanks, it works on that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Here's a question similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970211/microsoft-aspnetcore-app-2-1-1-upgrade-blocked-by-project/51026513#51026513)

Here's a sample .csproj. Be sure to have
`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>`

Make sure your project is on 2.2 before updating your packages to 2.2.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.1</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Gelf.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SlackLogger" Version="2.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.Linq" Version="3.5.21022.801" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Nozomi.Infra.Preprocessing\Nozomi.Infra.Preprocessing.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Nozomi.Infra.Service.Identity\Nozomi.Infra.Service.Identity.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Nozomi.Infra.Service\Nozomi.Infra.Service.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Areas\Identity\Pages\_ViewImports.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```